# XeLaTeX error when using nested tcolorbox listing environment inside custom xparse environment

Tags: xetex, environments, tcolorbox, minted, xparse

I want to start by saying I don't fully understand how environments work, so I apologize if this is turns out to be a bit out of topic.

## Desired behaviour

I'm trying to create a wrapper environment for `tcolorbox` with some default parameters, and I have defined a listing environment (`powershell`) with `tcolorbox` using `\newtcblisting`.

## The problem:

I tried creating a custom environment using `xparse`'s `NewDocumentEnvironment`, I'm also using `expl3` and `ltxdoc` because I need those for other sections of the document (I had to make some LaTeX magic to use `ltxdoc` with a book class).

I tried to locate where the error happens and it seems to be in the `powershell` environment.
Specifically I noticed the following:

- If I remove the powershell listing from the `defaultbox` environment it works as expected, and,
- If I don't use the `defaultbox` environment and directly use the `tcolorbox` environment inside the document the `powershell` environment works as expected.

## How to reproduce the error

The following code results on an error.

```tex
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\ReplaceClass{article}{book}
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[skins, minted, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\title{Title}

\author{Author}

\date{\today}

\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{Transparent}{gray}{1.0}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% | Creates a new tcolorbox environment with enhanced borders, breakable content, and a title.
\NewDocumentEnvironment { defaultbox } { o +b } {
  \IfNoValueTF {#1} {
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable]
      #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
  } {
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, title=#1]
      #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
  }
} {}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtcblisting{powershell}{
   enhanced,
   breakable,
   listing engine=minted,
   minted style=emacs,
   minted language=powershell,
   minted options={autogobble},
   colback=blue!5!white,
   colframe=Cerulean!75!black,
   listing only,
   left=5mm,enhanced,
   overlay={
      \begin{tcbclipinterior}
         \fill[Cerulean!20!white] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);
      \end{tcbclipinterior}
   }
}

\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono for Powerline}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\tcbset{listing engine=minted, colframe=Orchid!75!black}


\begin{document}
  \begin{defaultbox}[Box Title]
    Text
    \begin{powershell}
      [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = `
        [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
      Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
      Invoke-WebRequest "https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1" `
        -UseBasicParsing | Invoke-Expression
    \end{powershell}
  \end{defaultbox}
\end{document}
```

### Error output

The above code causes the following output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 22.1) (preloaded format=xelatex.fmt)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

(...)

Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ...cs/Escuela/software-design-book-es/test.tex
                                                  
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...cs/Escuela/software-design-book-es/test.tex
                                                  
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

---

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `powershell` environment is a verbatim environment (declared with `\newtcblisting`), which means you can't use it in the argument to another command.  When you define `\NewDocumentEnvironment { defaultbox } { o +b }`, it will grab its contents as argument, and break the verbatim environment.

But you don't have to grab the body of the environment.  You can define `defaultbox` as a regular environment:

```latex
\NewDocumentEnvironment { defaultbox } { o }
  {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
      {\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable]}
      {\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, title=#1]}%
  }
  {\end{tcolorbox}}
```

or even easier, define `defaultbox` with `\newtcolorbox`:

```latex
\newtcolorbox{defaultbox}[1][]
  {enhanced, breakable, title=#1}
```

then it will work:

> [image]

Full code:

```latex
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\ReplaceClass{article}{book}
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[skins, minted, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\title{Title}

\author{Author}

\date{\today}

\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{Transparent}{gray}{1.0}

% \ExplSyntaxOn
% % | Creates a new tcolorbox environment with enhanced borders, breakable content, and a title.
% \NewDocumentEnvironment { defaultbox } { o }
%   {%
%     \IfNoValueTF{#1}
%       {\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable]}
%       {\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, title=#1]}%
%   }
%   {\end{tcolorbox}}
% \ExplSyntaxOff

\newtcolorbox{defaultbox}[1][]
  {enhanced, breakable, title=#1}

\newtcblisting{powershell}{
   enhanced,
   breakable,
   listing engine=minted,
   minted style=emacs,
   minted language=powershell,
   minted options={autogobble},
   colback=blue!5!white,
   colframe=Cerulean!75!black,
   listing only,
   left=5mm,enhanced,
   overlay={
      \begin{tcbclipinterior}
         \fill[Cerulean!20!white] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);
      \end{tcbclipinterior}
   }
}

\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

% \setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmainfont{Fira Code}
\setmonofont{Fira Code}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\tcbset{listing engine=minted, colframe=Orchid!75!black}

\begin{document}
  \begin{defaultbox}
    Text
    \begin{powershell}
      [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = `
        [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
      Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
      Invoke-WebRequest "https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1" `
        -UseBasicParsing | Invoke-Expression
    \end{powershell}
  \end{defaultbox}
\end{document}
```